# grails / GORM / hibernate - hasMany map not synchronised on save() of parent

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, associations, grails-orm

Problem deleting associated entities and having this change persisted to the database.

Have a groovy object *parent* which has many *child* entities associated with it. When we find this domain object and set this list to null, and call *parent*.save(flush:true)
the *child* elements remain in the database. Would have expected these to have been deleted. Any suggestions would be great.

```
class Parent {

   static hasMany = [child:Child]
   ...
}
```

and the child:

```
class Child {

   belongsTo = [Parent]
   ...
}
```

we add the element and delete:

```
def child = new Child()

def parent = new Parent(child:child)

parent.save(flush:true)
def id = parent.id //from saved entity

/// in separate transaction

parent = Parent.get(id) //id from above
parent.child = null

parent.save(flush:true)

// check database - child reference still there - expect to have been deleted
```

Any suggestions about what we've done that wrong would be appreciated. using grails 1.3.5 (latest version).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing, you should use child.delete(flush:true) instead of assign null. It's just not approriate. (sorry for the previous mistake)

I recommend you read Peter Ledbrook series: http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/ . In your case, search "Deleting children"

Update: in case you still not read the above article (specifically useful):

To delete a child, you first need to remove it from the parent collection, then delete it. But it would cause property not null exception since you use belongsTo relation.

Solution: You can add this into Parent class:

```
static mapping = {
 childs cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
}
```

The above mapping will help delete all child that don't have a parent. Then you can use

```
parent.childs.clear()
```

Comment: your solution is basically what i said, just I didn't give it away.  I pointed him to the relevant documentation. Give a man a fish, he eats for a day, teach a man to fish, he eats for a lifetime....

Comment: Thanks for these comments; I haven't been able to get this to work and don't have further time budget for investigation at this stage. Attempted setting the cascade "all-delete-orphan" and also "all,delete-orphan". Also tried deleting each entry and calling clear, then adding the new rows, but this save staleObject exceptions. If i investigate again I may use logSql more to try and understand how hibernate is working and debug its configuration, but that will have to wait. Thank you for the answers provided.

Comment: @Alex: The clear command remove all the "child" in its parent collection, and with "all-delete-orphan", remove them as well. You don't need to call delete again. To truly understand how this works, as hvgotcodes mentions, you can't escape reading some documents.

Comment: Accepted - we have found that doing parentObject.child.clear() does clear associated elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
static mapping = 
{
   childs cascade: "all"
}
```

this works fine.